# How to use java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree in Scala

Tags: scala, java-7

I want to use the new `java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree` in Scala. And I was even successful:

```
class Visitor
   extends
      java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor [java.nio.file.Path]
   {
   override def visitFile(
      File : java.nio.file.Path,
      Attrs : java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes) : java.nio.file.FileVisitResult =
   {
      if (! File.toString.contains(".svn"))
      {
         System.out.println(File);
      } // if

      java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
   } // visitFile
} // Visitor

java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree (Project_Home, new Visitor)
```

But while this code works fine I feels a bit like carrying Java paradigms into Scala. So a question to the true Scala Gurus: Is there anything I could improve or is this just it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Visitor is really a `foreach` without the benefit of functions, so let's make a `foreach`. The method is static, but it takes as first argument a `Path`, so we'll enrich `Path` with a `foreach` method, which is done with something like this:

```
import java.nio.file._
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes

implicit def fromNioPath(path: Path): TraverseFiles = new TraversePath(path)
```

And everything else is inside the `TraversePath` class, which looks somewhat like this:

```
class TraversePath(path: Path) {
  def foreach(f: (Path, BasicFileAttributes) => Unit) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This is enough for you to write this:

```
ProjectHome foreach ((file, _) => if (!file.toString.contains(".svn")) println(File))
```

Of course, it won't actually do anything, so let's get it to do something:

```
class TraversePath(path: Path) {
  def foreach(f: (Path, BasicFileAttributes) => Unit) {
    class Visitor extends SimpleFileVisitor[Path] {
      override def visitFile(file: Path, attrs: BasicFileAttributes): FileVisitResult = try { 
        f(file, attrs)
        FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
      } catch { 
        case _ => FileVisitResult.TERMINATE
      }
    }
    Files.walkFileTree(path, new Visitor)
  }
}
```

There, now that line will do the same thing as your code did! However, we can improve it further. It happens that `foreach` is the only method required of `Traversable`, so we can extend that class, and get all the methods of a Scala collection!

The only problem is that a `Traversable.foreach` function takes only one argument, and here we are taking two. We can change it into receive a tuple, though. Here's the full code:

```
import java.nio.file._
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes
import scala.collection.Traversable

// Make it extend Traversable
class TraversePath(path: Path) extends Traversable[(Path, BasicFileAttributes)] {

  // Make foreach receive a function from Tuple2 to Unit
  def foreach(f: ((Path, BasicFileAttributes)) => Unit) {
    class Visitor extends SimpleFileVisitor[Path] {
      override def visitFile(file: Path, attrs: BasicFileAttributes): FileVisitResult = try {
        // Pass a tuple to f
        f(file -> attrs)
        FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
      } catch { 
        case _ => FileVisitResult.TERMINATE
      }
    }
    Files.walkFileTree(path, new Visitor)
  }
}

ProjectHome foreach {
  // use case to seamlessly deconstruct the tuple
  case (file, _) => if (!file.toString.contains(".svn")) println(File)
}
```

Disclaimer: I have tested none of this code, because I don't have Java 7 installed. There are probably some bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Taking [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8927040/1527244) as fundament, I have worked a little to make `Path` accessible with convenient implicits, as you are used in collections. Notice that not all functions are included.

```
class TraversePath(path: Path) {
    def foreach(f: (Path, BasicFileAttributes) => Unit) {
        Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor[Path] {
            override def visitFile(file: Path, attrs: BasicFileAttributes) = {
                f(file, attrs)
                FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
            }
        })
    }

    /**
     * foreach that takes FileVisitResult instead of Unit
     */
    def foreach2(f: (Path, BasicFileAttributes) => FileVisitResult) {
        Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor[Path] {
            override def visitFile(file: Path, attrs: BasicFileAttributes) = f(file, attrs)
        })
    }

    def foldLeft[T](t: T)(f: (T, Path) => T) = {
        var current = t
        foreach((p, _) => current = f(current, p))
        current
    }

    def forall(f: Path => Boolean) = {
        var ret = true
        foreach2((p, _) =>
            if ( !f(path) ) {
                ret = false
                FileVisitResult.TERMINATE
            }
            else
                FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
        )
        ret
    }

    def exists(f: Path => Boolean) = {
        var ret = false
        foreach2((p, _) =>
            if ( f(path) ) {
                ret = true
                FileVisitResult.TERMINATE
            }
            else
                FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
        )
    }

    /**
     * Directly modifies the underlying path.
     */
    def mapReal(f: Path => Path) = foreach((p, _) => Files.move(p, f(p)))

    /**
     * @param f map function
     * @return a left-folded list with the map function applied to each element
     */
    def map(f: Path => Path) = foldLeft(Nil: List[Path]) {
        case (xs, p) => xs ::: f(p) :: Nil
    }

    def find(f: Path => Boolean) = {
        var k = None: Option[Path]
        foreach2((p, _) =>
            if ( f(p) ) {
                k = Some(p)
                FileVisitResult.TERMINATE
            } else FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
        )
        k
    }
}

implicit def fromNioPath(path: Path) = new TraversePath(path)
```

The java.nio API is extremely powerful and is, IMHO, very sufficing for use with Scala. With these implicits (and more, if you want to write some functions), it is very simple to accomplish even harder tasks.

You could use this now by writing something like this:

```
val path1 = Paths.get(sys.props("user.home"), "workspace")

val path2 = Paths.get(sys.props("user.home"), "workspace2")

val list1 = path1.foldLeft(Nil: List[Path]) {
    (xs, p) => xs ::: path1.relativize(p) :: Nil
}
val list2 = path2.foldLeft(Nil: List[Path]) {
    (xs, p) => xs ::: path2.relativize(p) :: Nil
}
(list1 diff list2) foreach println
```

Regards,
Danyel

Answer (score 2):

Here's Daniel's script made compilable:

```
import java.nio.file._
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes
import scala.collection.Traversable

// Make it extend Traversable
class TraversePath(path: Path) extends Traversable[(Path, BasicFileAttributes)] {

  // Make foreach receive a function from Tuple2 to Unit
  def foreach[U](f: ((Path, BasicFileAttributes)) => U) {
    class Visitor extends SimpleFileVisitor[Path] {
      override def visitFile(file: Path, attrs: BasicFileAttributes): FileVisitResult = try {
        // Pass a tuple to f
        f(file -> attrs)
        FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
      } catch { 
        case _ => FileVisitResult.TERMINATE
      }
    }
    Files.walkFileTree(path, new Visitor)
  }
}
val projectHome = new TraversePath(Paths.get("."))

projectHome foreach { 
  // use case to seamlessly deconstruct the tuple
  case (file:Path, attr:BasicFileAttributes) => if (!file.toString.contains(".svn")) println(file)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make your code a bit more pretty, but at the end of the day it would still look like the plain old visitor pattern.

Comment: I would avoid resorting to Gnawing Fatalism Patterns when answering. Others here gave nice answers on how to abstract,  in Scala's Style, over the Java's underlying Visitor Pattern. The constructs like Paths.get("/home/gnaw").foreach | map | foldLeft ... abstract over it in the same way  all the rest abstracts over the Visiting Pattern of the RAM cells (memory access).

Answer (score 0):

FIles.walkFileTree example to compare two directories / synchronizing two directories
for file difference

```
private static void compareDirectories(String srcPath, String destPath) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("sync. started....");
    final Path mainDir = Paths.get(srcPath);
    final Path otherDir = Paths.get(destPath);

    // Walk thru mainDir directory
    Files.walkFileTree(mainDir, new FileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path path,
                BasicFileAttributes atts) throws IOException {
            return visitFile(path, atts);
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes mainAtts)
                throws IOException {
            // I've seen two implementations on windows and MacOSX. One has passed the relative path, one the absolute path.
            // This works in both cases
            Path relativePath = mainDir.relativize(mainDir.resolve(path));
            File tmpFile = new File(otherDir+"/"+relativePath);

                if(tmpFile.exists()) {
                    BasicFileAttributes otherAtts = Files.readAttributes(otherDir.resolve(relativePath), BasicFileAttributes.class);
                    // Do your comparison logic here: we are skipping directories as all directories are traversed automatically
                    if(!new File(path.toString()).isDirectory()) {
                                                    //write your logic for comparing files
                        compareEntries(mainDir, otherDir, relativePath, mainAtts, otherAtts);
                    }
                    else {
                        File src = new File(path.toString());

                                                   //write your logic here for comparing directories
                                                   compareDirectories(src,tmpFile.toPath().toString()+"/"+s);
                    }
                }
                else {
                                            //this function will copy missing files in destPath from srcPath recursive function till depth of directory structure
                    copyFolderOrFiles(new File(path.toString()), tmpFile);
                }
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path path,
                IOException exc) throws IOException {
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path path, IOException exc)
                throws IOException {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            // If the root directory has failed it makes no sense to continue
            return (path.equals(mainDir))? FileVisitResult.TERMINATE:FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on the ideas of the other posts. I like the solution where we can match over case classes. The following code just returns a collection of strings for the different events that the visitor would have been called on.

```
FileWalker(java.nio.file.Paths.get(" your dir ")).map({
    case PreVisitDirectory(dir, atts) => s"about to visit dir ${dir}"
    case PostVisitDirectory(dir, exc) => s"have visited dir ${dir}"
    case VisitFile(file, attrs) => s"visiting file ${file}"
    case VisitFileFailed(file, exc) => s"failed to visit ${file}"
})
```

The implementation of FileWalker is:

```
import java.io.IOException
import java.nio.file.{FileVisitResult, Files, Path, SimpleFileVisitor}
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes

trait FileVisitEvent
case class PreVisitDirectory(path: Path, atts: BasicFileAttributes) extends FileVisitEvent
case class PostVisitDirectory(dir: Path, exc: IOException) extends FileVisitEvent
case class VisitFile(file: Path, attrs: BasicFileAttributes) extends FileVisitEvent
case class VisitFileFailed(file: Path, exc: IOException) extends FileVisitEvent

/**
  * Scala style walker for a directory tree
  *
  * Is a treversable over the tree which traverses different event types extending {{FileVisitEvent}}
  *
  * @param from
  */
class FileWalker(from: Path) extends Traversable[FileVisitEvent] {
  // just to simplify error handling
  def wrapper(x: => Unit): FileVisitResult = try {
    x
    FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
  }
  catch {
    case _ : Throwable => FileVisitResult.TERMINATE
  }

  override def foreach[U](f: (FileVisitEvent) => U): Unit = {
    Files.walkFileTree(from, new SimpleFileVisitor[Path] {
      override def preVisitDirectory(dir: Path, atts: BasicFileAttributes): FileVisitResult =
        wrapper( f(PreVisitDirectory(dir, atts)))

      override def postVisitDirectory(dir: Path, exc: IOException): FileVisitResult =
        wrapper(f(PostVisitDirectory(dir, exc)))

      override def visitFile(file: Path, attrs: BasicFileAttributes): FileVisitResult =
        wrapper(f(VisitFile( file, attrs ) ))

      override def visitFileFailed(file: Path, exc: IOException): FileVisitResult =
        wrapper( f(VisitFileFailed( file, exc ) ))
    })
  }
}

object FileWalker {
  def apply( from : Path ) = new FileWalker( from )
}
```